# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate my php gallery function, using jQuery functions. `thmb_animation` function has to enlarge image in new location with `mouseenter` function. When debugging the script i get TypeError. I have tried using `jQuery.noConflict()` because googling usually refered to it, but it didnt do the job, so i ended up here.

```
$(function thumb_animation() {

        var thumb = $('.st_thumb img');
        var img = $('#bigImg');
        var h = $(window).height();
        thumb.on('mouseenter',function (e) <---- Here comes TypError
{
        var thumbSource = e.target.src;

    img.attr('src',thumbSource);
    console.log(e);
    img.show("fade", 2000);
    img.animate({height:'60%',width:'66%'}, {queue: false});


}); 
thumb.mouseleave(function() {

img.animate({height:'0%', width:'0%'}, {queue: false});

});
});
```

HTML part :

```
<div class='wrap'>  
<ul id="st_nav" class="st_navigation">
            <li class="album">
                <div class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                    <div class="st_thumbs">
                        <?php showGallery(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li> 
        </ul>
 <div class='gallery'>
 <img id='bigImg' src='images/album/thumbs/2.jpeg'>
 </div>
```

Entire error message :

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionscripts.js:21 thumb_animationjquery.min.js:26 c.extend.readyjquery.min.js:33 L`

Solution for the error message :

I was using older version of jQuery.
But the image still doesnt show show in new location.

Comment: Post the entire error message and post the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: `thumb` has no function called `on`. You now want to inspect `thumb` with `console.log`

Comment: `on` was added to jQuery in version 1.7. I'm guessing you have an older version.

Comment: Check that `$('.st_thumb img')` actually returns something. It could be that you're trying to declare a `on.('mouseenter', ...)` on an empty variable (`thumb`)

Comment: I got rid of the error message, truly i was using jQuery version of 1.4.2, but the image still wont animate in the position. `console.log(thumb); `output is `[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".st_thumb img", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]`

Comment: @JuuriPeeter Looks like Rory found the answer to this question. Ask him to post his comment as an answer and select it, then ask a new question. You will get many new reviewers and get your problem solved.

Comment: Rory can you please post your comment as an answer to the question please! Thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted as correct answer.  (Juuri, you don't need to wait to post the new question - post immediately if you have not already)

Comment: Thanks gibberish, @JuuriPeeter I've added an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on` was added to jQuery in version 1.7. I'm guessing you have an older version and need to upgrade. I would suggest `1.11` if you need to support < IE9, other wise `2.x`.